# Are hardware recommendation or technical issues on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've seen questions like these, about technical issues, cables, electronics...

[What's the best way to connect two iPods to one set of amplified speakers?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/564/whats-the-best-way-to-connect-two-ipods-to-one-set-of-amplified-speakers/565) **Score: 5, status: Open**

<s>[Dorset Crosley Record Player table not turning](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/5239/dorset-crosley-record-player-table-not-turning) **Score: 1, status: Closed**</s>

[Turntable spins faster after moving to a new country with different power spec](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/3518/turntable-spins-faster-after-moving-to-a-new-country-with-different-power-spec) **Score:1, status: Open**

[Why is my turntable playing at uneven speed?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/720/why-is-my-turntable-playing-at-uneven-speed) **Score: 5, status: Open**

### Product Recommendation

<s>[Product Question: Fadedge Beats Solo S450](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/1147/product-question-fadedge-beats-solo-s450) **Score: 1, status: Closed**</s>

---

I haven't seen any clear rule about this so I wonder if these questions are on-topic. I feel that these questions are out of scope, but they are still accepted. What are the rules on these?

Comment: The second question you link should be closed IMO. Product recommendation questions are off-topic pretty much everywhere on the SE network.

Comment: @Mast, OK, I understand the product recommendation, but what about the other cases...?

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, given our relatively low traffic and question rate, we should allow any answerable, non-spam, non-solely-opinion questions that are in any way on topic, and aren't already covered by another site.

I think the rule in the past has been: instruments and performance/recording equipment questions go to music SE, product recommendations are banned, but music enjoyment equipment questions (record players, home speakers, etc.) ARE on topic here.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, **product recommendation** are clearly off-topic, for several reasons:

- Primarily opinion based: people will argue about their favourite brands and models, and there is no possible definitive answer.
- Time dependent: I suppose, Stack Exchange questions and answers shouldn't be time dependent and **product recommendation are time dependant** (a supposed best product for this or that won't be the same in 5 years) so this kind of questions would require a constant update.